# How can I override margin-block-start?

Tags: html, css

I included normalize.css
I have margin:0 on the header elements
I have margin:0 on every class on the page

https://www.christianlong.design/SuperSmashBrosDB/phptest6.php

I can't figure out how to change the margin of the h3 elements for the life of me.

Comment: From Review: Please share your source code also.

Comment: Modify class *cardTitle* in style.css. Also: *font: 30px;* is invalid. That should be *font-size*.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>. For more information, please see How to Ask and take the tour <https://stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp I included the link so you can click view page source, I could've mentioned that I guess.

Comment: @Gerard Thanks I actually got a little tripped up on that

Comment: @quant My first idea: put margin:0 on all elements. Second idea: try normalize.css. Third idea: searched stack overflow for margin-block-start questions and header tag default margins. Couldn't find info that worked on how to actually change the default margin on h3 tag. After an hour and no more resources left, I decided to ask for help. The answer to my question was that there is no solution and I have to use divs instead of h3, and I would've wasted more time trying to figure that out on my own Edit: Is this the proper way to create a stack overflow question? I'll include all this next time

Comment: Chris, you must include your source code in your question, even if there is a link to your source code, because when the link gets broken, or the source code in your link changes, your question won't be affected by that. This is very important for the community of SO, please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53203111/edit) your question and add your source code to it for the posterity. You can understand that by observing  that at least 2 reviewers upvoted my first comment on your question. This is the way SO got so useful for everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

e.g Chrome Browser has some defaults at the user agent for some blocks:

```
h3 {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

You can reset with:

```
margin-block-start:0; margin-block-end:0; margin-inline-start:0; margin-inline-end:0;
padding-block-start:0; padding-block-end:0; padding-inline-start:0; padding-inline-end:0;
```

Comment: I was going to upvote this, since it appears to be true, but the question remains: why is it so hard to override browser user agent styles like margin-block-start? `margin:0` won't work. Is there a normalize.css around that does this for all elements? I ran into this problem for navigation uls, but it may apply in many other cases, such as <h1> here.

Answer (score -2):

Just ran into the same issue, what helped me is to use !important to override this for good.
Just like this:

```
h3 { 
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

It might not be the best solution, but [here's a good article](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) on uses of that rule.

Comment: You seem to have read the article and completely missed the most !important (pun intended) implementation of using an override is to make it specific to a _class_, not a native element. One final note, anything _you_ do can always, I mean always, be overridden by the user themselves. Understanding that, and building not for you, but for the most users possible, will often direct one away from hard-line approaches such as using !important to "get the job done".